# What should I use to prime an old plaster wall before skim-coating with new plaster?

Tags: plaster

Should I use oil-based primer on an old plaster wall (as a bonding agent) before skim-coating new plaster over it?

Answer (score 2):

No, use a weak solution of PVA in water (5 parts water to 1 part PVA) instead.

Paint the wall with this and leave to dry, then re-skim.

Comment: I understood PVA was used to prime drywall.  Is this also used for plaster walls?

Comment: @RET You can use on old plaster too. We had the kitchen ceiling reskimmed and the plasterer used it, and we've used it to seal a bedroom ceiling before papering it.

Comment: @ChrisF does it matter if the old plaster is premix or setting type plaster?